# IE7 outline:0 not working

Tags: jquery, html, css, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-7

I understand the the outline is used for accessibility but what's another way of doing:

```
a {
   outline: 0;
}
```

something that works in IE7

using Jquery perhaps?

Comment: IE7 doesn't even support `outline`. What are you asking?

Comment: @thirtydot: Presumably he's asking for an alternative that does work.

Comment: @BoltClock: His example has `outline: 0`, so in IE7 he wants to get rid of something that isn't even there? I don't get it.

Comment: @thirtydot: IE7 does draw an outline when you click a link, but you're not able to control it using `outline`. At least, that's what I can remember from my few hours of using it...

Comment: @BoltClock: so the question still remains, is there a solution to making the outline go away?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For jquery you can try something like this

```
$('a').focus(function() {
  $(this).blur();
});
```

It's essentially the same thing as the IE 7 only solution, it says when anchor is focused, blur it. I tried this on Mac VM IE 7 and it works

http://jsfiddle.net/QnMLR/2/

the top one has the outline and bottom one does not

Comment: this works, but messes up the tab order as it will bounce back to the previous item.

Comment: Forgot to surround it with jquery's .ready function and then it worked. $(function () { ... });

Answer (score 1):

now used to `focus`

```
a:hover, a:active, a:focus{
outline:0;
}
```

more info http://css-tricks.com/removing-the-dotted-outline/

---

Updated ie solution is

```
a:focus, *:focus {
    noFocusLine: expression(this.onFocus=this.blur());
}
```

more info http://www.cssjunction.com/css/remove-dotted-border-in-ie7/

Comment: Thanks for posting anyway... :)

Answer (score 1):

This works as well using jquery and doesn't mess up the tab order:

```
$(function ()
{
    $("a").each(function() {
        $(this).attr("hideFocus", "true").css("outline", "none");
    });
});
```

Comment: This should be the best answer. It's the only one that uses IE's proprietary "[hideFocus](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533783(v=vs.85).aspx)" property.

Answer (score 0):

I think the _noFocusLine do work in IE7

```
a{
    outline: none;
    _noFocusLine: expression(this.hideFocus=true);
}
```

I found this from [here](http://rodleviton.com/blog/remove-dotted-border-on-ie7-links) , and I have tried it by myself.
Hope this will help you.