# Remove highlight from active button

Tags: html, css

I have a couple of buttons styled as tabs for an options menu. Everything looks like I want and it's working fine.  The only problem I have is the blue highlight on the active button.  How can I remove it?

[image: Blue Highlight on Active Button]

For reasons I don't understand, my code snippet does not reproduce the problem.

```js
function ShowCurrent()
{
 document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu";
 document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu off";
}

function ShowFuture()
{
 document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu";
 document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu off";
}
```

```css
.menu
{
 border: 2px solid grey;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 3px 2px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5;
}

.off
{
 border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
 padding: 2px;
}

.placeholder
{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <button id="btnCurrent" class="menu" onClick="ShowCurrent();">Current</button>
 <button id="btnFuture" class="menu off" onClick="ShowFuture();">Future</button>
</div>

<div class="placeholder">Just hanging out, taking up space</div>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360979/ie7-outline0-not-working

Comment: Okay, I got it.  Adding .blur() to the javascript when the button is selected clears the blue highlight.

Comment: Great, can I suggest it as a dupe to that post?

Comment: I agree that the questions is the same but the solutions are different.  Perhaps I should also post my answer there?

Comment: No, hang on.  That question is styling A tags, not buttons.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to everyone for your suggestions.

As this is a Windows Desktop Gadget I am working on the engine is IE7 and it doesn't support the CSS outline property.  As these are buttons, which have done their jobs as soon as they are clicked, there is no need for them to keep focus.  I have found that adding:

```
document.getElementById(theButton).blur();
```

to the javascript when the button is selected clears the blue highlight.

There is a similar problem with A tags addressed with jquery here: [IE7 outline:0 not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11360979/ie7-outline0-not-working/11362571#11362571)

Comment: Please don't do this. Use the CSS options instead. What you are doing is losing focus. So when the user clicks it, you immediately remove focus. That's not what you want. Use CSS instead.

Comment: Actually, @BramVanroy, this is exactly what I want.  There is no CSS option that will work in this situation.  I don't appreciate the down vote when you don't understand the problem and solution in their entireties.  I am the person who posted the question, and after trying all the other suggestions, this is the solution that works.  You need to understand that these are buttons.  Once clicked, they have done their job. There is no reason they need to maintain the focus.

Comment: Even though I still disagree, you are right in saying that I shouldn't have downvoted this. However, since it's an hour ago I can't undo the downvote. Therefore I upvoted your question. imho, a CSS approach is always better than any JS work-around. But if this fits your needs, go for it.

Comment: I agree that CSS would be better.  This is rendering in IE7 which doesn't support outline, which is why CSS doesn't work here.  The reason for IE7 is that this is actually code from a Windows Desktop Gadget that I am working on and the gadget engine is IE7 only. @BramVanroy

Comment: @BramVanroy I've edited my answer to include a better explanation of why this is needed and why it works.  Please see if you approve now.  And yes, I absolutely agree that a pure CSS solution would have been better.  It was when I couldn't find one that I posted this question.

Comment: @Lance I guess it would be better to also include the link of http://stackoverflow.com/a/11362571/483779 into the answer. Different tags but same idea.

Comment: @Pangloss Done! Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Just add `outline:0`

```js
function ShowCurrent() {
  document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu";
  document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu off";
}

function ShowFuture() {
  document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu";
  document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu off";
}
```

```css
button.menu {
  border: 2px solid grey;
  border-bottom: none;
  margin-bottom: -2px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  padding: 3px 2px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 5;
  outline: 0;
}
button.off {
  border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
  padding: 2px;
}
.placeholder {
  border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btnCurrent" class="menu" onClick="ShowCurrent();">Current</button>
  <button id="btnFuture" class="menu off" onClick="ShowFuture();">Future</button>
</div>

<div class="placeholder">Just hanging out, taking up space</div>
```

Comment: Is it the _outline: 0;_ you added?  It's not working for me in the actual application.

Comment: @Lance Yeah you sure you added it to `button.menu` ?

Comment: I did, exactly as you showed it.  If it matters, this is rendering in IE7.

Comment: @Lance Can you try it on some other browser ?

Comment: Okay, I opened the page in IE11 and the problem doesn't exist at all.  So apparently, it's only an issue in earlier browsers.

Comment: @Lance [caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=outline) doesn't have anything about outlines on IE7 so i am not sure

Comment: @Lance You should add it to `button.menu:focus`

Comment: @LarsW Ususally setting `outline:0` will do it but i don't know about IE7

Comment: No joy.  So to be clear, it doesn't have the outline on HOVER or ACTIVE.  It only shows on the last-clicked button after you leave the button.  I tried adding outline: 0; to :visited but that didn't work either.

Comment: @Lance I moved that comment under the question, and don't have a machine to test it.

Answer (score 2):

add

```
outline:0;
```

in the css

```js
function ShowCurrent()
{
 document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu";
 document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu off";
}

function ShowFuture()
{
 document.getElementById('btnFuture').className = "menu";
 document.getElementById('btnCurrent').className = "menu off";
}
```

```css
.menu
{
 border: 2px solid grey;
 border-bottom: none;
 margin-bottom: -2px;
 margin-right: 5px;
 padding: 3px 2px;
 position: relative;
 z-index: 5;
    outline:0;
}

.off
{
 border-bottom: 2px solid grey;
 padding: 2px;
}

.placeholder
{
    border: 2px solid grey;
}
```

```html
<div>
 <button id="btnCurrent" class="menu" onClick="ShowCurrent();">Current</button>
 <button id="btnFuture" class="menu off" onClick="ShowFuture();">Future</button>
</div>

<div class="placeholder">Just hanging out, taking up space</div>
```